# Родительский репозиторий git для нескольких дочерних репозиториев git

Tags: git, github, repository

У меня есть несколько репозиториев, например, Child1, Child2, ..., ChildN. Все эти репозитории на моем компьютере находятся в одной родительской папке с именем Parent. Parent - это не репозиторий git. Я хочу сделать Parent репозиторием git, который будет содержать все дочерние репозитории, и когда я буду клонировать родительский репозиторий git на другом компьютере, он будет клонировать родительский и все дочерние репозитории, и когда я внесу некоторые изменения в один из дочерних репозиториев в Parent  репозиторий также должны быть внесены эти изменения, кроме Child/.idea и Child/node_modules, и когда я запущу git pull в родительском репозитории, дочерние репозитории также должны быть запулены

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю Вам требуется использовать подмодули git

Подмодули позволяют вам сохранить один Git-репозиторий, как поддиректорию другого Git-репозитория. Это даёт вам возможность склонировать в ваш проект другой репозиторий, но коммиты при этом хранить отдельно.

Вы можете почитать о этом более подробно [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).